# How to multiply a list in scheme?

Tags: scheme

New to scheme but trying to learn the basics.

Let's say I passed a list in as a parameter and I wanted to multiply each element by `-1`. Right now I have this:

```
(define (negative b)
 (* (car b) -1 )))
```

Which returns the first element as `-1 *` that element

So in this case giving it `(negative '(5 1 2 3))` returns `-5`.

But lets say I want it to return

```
-5 -1 -2 -3
```

How would I go about making the rest of the list negative? Using cdr recursively?

Comment: What's the purpose of the first argument?

Comment: What is a `-5 -1 -2 -3`? Can you make an expression that produces that strange value?

Answer (score 3):

Do it recursively.

```
(define (negative l)
  (if (null? l)
      '()
      (cons (* (car l) -1)
            (negative (cdr l)))))
```

If the list is empty, this just returns an empty list, as the base case.

Otherwise, it calculates `-1 *` the first element, the negative of the rest of the list, and combines them to produce the result.

Comment: @jpyams It doesn't happen when using a decent code editor, but the SO editor doesn't help you balance parens. I have this problem in every language here on SO.

Comment: The emacs-mode for SO is really easy to install: https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el

Comment: @coredump Nice, except I'm still running Emacs 22.x on my Mac (I have a huge number of old Emacs add-ons that don't work with newer versions).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of your exercise may be for you to code up your own map procedure, in which case that's fine.  But if not, use scheme's built in 'map' procedure which is intended for just this kind of purpose.

'map' has been available at least since R4RS (that is, a long time ago) and possibly earlier.

Answer (score 0):

by using map. If you want it returned as list.

It would be like this

```
(define negative
  (lambda (b)
    (map - b)))
```

Map is going through list b, and apply procedure "-" to each number in list

If you want to return as single numbers not in list you apply values on the list.

```
(define negative1
  (lambda (b)
    (apply values (map - b))))
```

**Edit:** I saw that you are asking for recursive solution, which would go like this

```
(define negative1
  (lambda (b)
    (if (null? b)
      '()
    (cons (- (car b)) (negative1 (cdr b))))))
```